# My surface laptop keyboard is not working

Tags: drivers

I have a surface laptop 2. My keyboard does not work on ubuntu. How can I fix this? My mouse works just fine.

Comment: What release are you using?  What kernel option did you use? (ie. HWE or GA if using a LTS release). Selecting a newer kernel stack may be a first step, but you've provided no details on which to start.

Comment: This is the kernel version                           
 Linux 5.4.0-29-generic and the relese version is 20.04